# Delete even pages in VBA (PowerPoint)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I delete even pages in a PowerPoint document using VBA?

I have about 750 pages, so I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Please make a little effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 0 Step -1
    If i mod 2 = 1 Then ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Delete
Next
```